# getting object reference error when want to set the start page as a blog

Tags: nullreferenceexception, lemoon

I created a blog page in Lemoon CMS. 
I liked lemoon cms very much but I have a problem when I want to set this blog as a start page.

If I set start page settings as my blog page I get this error message on Site.Master line 12
"object reference not to set an instance of an object"

"<% if (!Start.FeedUrl.IsNullOrEmpty()) { %>"

What should I do ?

Also I get the same error message If I want to set created pages to start page.

My system information is 
Mindroute.Core: 4.6.0.36
Mindroute.Lemoon: 4.6.0.36

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

The master page in the project template assumes that the start page of the site is an item of type StartPage (as you can see in the code behind on Site.Master.cs). If you change the start page to a Blog you need to modify the master page accordingly.